# Saving inside the for loop in each iteration in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, rest, for-loop, angular-promise, angular-resource

I try to add elements to DB inside the for-loop. Only one goes to DB and then I got a 500 (Internal Server Error) for duplicate key. Strange thing is that in javaScript log I got two reasonList objects in a row and after that it goes to save and tries to save two times the same object, the last one.

**Glassfish error log**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4-3-6' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**In controller I try to save rma and reasonList at the same time**

```
savedRma = rmaService.save({}, rma);
savedRma.$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.rma = result;
    console.log('result.rmaID--------->'+ result.rmaId);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reasonList.length; i++) {
        $scope.rmaHasDefectdesc.rmaHasDefectdescPK.defectdescDefectdescId = reasonList[i].defectdescId;
        $scope.rmaHasDefectdesc.rmaHasDefectdescPK.returnreasonId = reasonList[i].returnreasonReturnreasonId.returnreasonId;
        $scope.rmaHasDefectdesc.rmaHasDefectdescPK.rmaId = $scope.rma.rmaId;

        console.log('defectDescID: ' +reasonList[i].defectdescId);
        console.log('returnReasonID: ' +reasonList[i].returnreasonReturnreasonId.returnreasonId)
        console.log('rmaID: ' +$scope.rma.rmaId);

        savedRmaHasDefectdesc = rmaDefectSvc.save({}, $scope.rmaHasDefectdesc);
        savedRmaHasDefectdesc.$promise.then(function (response) {
            $scope.savedRmaHasDefectdesc = response;
            console.log('response.rmaHasDefectdescPK--------->'+ response.rmaHasDefectdescPK.defectdescDefectdescId);
            console.log('response.rmaHasDefectdescPK.returnreasonId--------->'+ response.rmaHasDefectdescPK.returnreasonId);
            console.log('response.rmaHasDefectdescPK.rmaId--------->'+ response.rmaHasDefectdescPK.rmaId);
        });
  } //FOR LOOP ENDS   
});//savedRma.promise.then ENDS
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Question 1 - I could not make out what you are asking and question 2 - Best that you check the server and determine why the request returned 500 status - My guess is that you are creating records which already exist (same ID).

Comment: I also don't understand the question. If you have 2 questions, ask 2 questions. Simplify :-)

Comment: @callmekatootie Q1: After saving the rma-object, I need the ramID, which is auto increment field in mySql DB, but I can't get it automatically, field is empty. Q2: Good guess, but unfortunately wrong, there is something else.

Comment: @Sami I am afraid your question still needs improvement. For example, where does the above code lie? In a controller or in a service or somewhere else? What is the above piece of code expected to do? Finally, if you get 500 error, it indicates a server side error. You have necessarily check the server side code and verify why it returns with status 500.

Comment: @TonyBarnes I split this to two questions. Here is question 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294329/resource-save-not-invoking-callback-when-using-ngresource-in-angularjs